# How to match an array to another array with its exact indexes (C# - ASP.NET Core)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have an array with these specs. It will return Excel headers for exporting it. I want this return these headers translated to another language. how can I match this to another array with these exact indexes for passing instead of this.

```
var properties = new[]
        {
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderId", p => p.Id),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("StoreId", p => p.StoreId),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderGuid", p => p.OrderGuid, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("CustomerId", p => p.CustomerId, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderStatusId", p => p.OrderStatusId, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("PaymentStatusId", p => p.PaymentStatusId),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingStatusId", p => p.ShippingStatusId, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderSubtotalInclTax", p => p.OrderSubtotalInclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderSubtotalExclTax", p => p.OrderSubtotalExclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax", p => p.OrderSubTotalDiscountInclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderSubTotalDiscountExclTax", p => p.OrderSubTotalDiscountExclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderShippingInclTax", p => p.OrderShippingInclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderShippingExclTax", p => p.OrderShippingExclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("PaymentMethodAdditionalFeeInclTax", p => p.PaymentMethodAdditionalFeeInclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("PaymentMethodAdditionalFeeExclTax", p => p.PaymentMethodAdditionalFeeExclTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("TaxRates", p => p.TaxRates, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderTax", p => p.OrderTax, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderTotal", p => p.OrderTotal, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("RefundedAmount", p => p.RefundedAmount, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("OrderDiscount", p => p.OrderDiscount, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("CurrencyRate", p => p.CurrencyRate),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("CustomerCurrencyCode", p => p.CustomerCurrencyCode),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("AffiliateId", p => p.AffiliateId, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("PaymentMethodSystemName", p => p.PaymentMethodSystemName, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingPickupInStore", p => p.PickupInStore, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingMethod", p => p.ShippingMethod),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingRateComputationMethodSystemName", p => p.ShippingRateComputationMethodSystemName, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("CustomValuesXml", p => p.CustomValuesXml, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("VatNumber", p => p.VatNumber, ignore),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("CreatedOnUtc", p => p.CreatedOnUtc.ToOADate()),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingFirstName", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.FirstName ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingLastName", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.LastName ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingEmail", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.Email ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingCompany", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.Company ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingStateProvince", async p => (await _ctateProvinceService.GetStateProvinceByAddressAsync(await orderBillingAddress(p)))?.Name ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingCity", async p => (await _cityService.GetCityByAddressAsync(await orderBillingAddress(p)))?.Name ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingCounty", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.County ?? string.Empty),
            //new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingCity", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.City ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingAddress1", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.Address1 ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingAddress2", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.Address2 ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingZipPostalCode", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.ZipPostalCode ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingPhoneNumber", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.PhoneNumber ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("BillingFaxNumber", async p => (await orderBillingAddress(p))?.FaxNumber ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingFirstName", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.FirstName ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingLastName", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.LastName ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingEmail", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.Email ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingCompany", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.Company ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingStateProvince", async p => (await _ctateProvinceService.GetStateProvinceByAddressAsync(await orderAddress(p)))?.Name ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingCity", async p => (await _cityService.GetCityByAddressAsync(await orderAddress(p)))?.Name ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingCounty", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.County ?? string.Empty),
            //new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingCity", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.City ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingAddress1", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.Address1 ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingAddress2", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.Address2 ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingZipPostalCode", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.ZipPostalCode ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingPhoneNumber", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.PhoneNumber ?? string.Empty),
            new PropertyByName<Order>("ShippingFaxNumber", async p => (await orderAddress(p))?.FaxNumber ?? string.Empty)
        };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.

Comment: Could you please share some more details with which array you would to compare here `"I match this to another array"`?